# Why doesn't my date conversion solution work any more, despite nothing changing?

Tags: r, date, date-conversion

I wrote an R script several months ago and part of that script converts character dates into date format.

I initially encountered this problem where `NA`s were being introduced when I converted characters to date format.

It was suggested that the reason this happened was because it must be expecting the `day` element of the date to be two characters, - such as `June 12th 2018` - and only failed when the `day` element contained a single character - such as `June 2nd 2018`.

The proffered solution (`as.Date(df$date, format='%B %d %Y')`)  worked perfectly.

Until now.

Not only do I get `NA` values, I also receive the error: `Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (12, 14), (13, 16)`.

I don't know what this means - can somebody explain?

This is the original data frame:

```
                    time.per.day                 Top.0.type Count
1   July 27th 2018, 00:00:00.000      conversation-archived     2
2   July 27th 2018, 00:00:00.000      conversation-archived     1
3   July 28th 2018, 00:00:00.000      conversation-archived     4
4   July 28th 2018, 00:00:00.000      conversation-archived     1
5   July 29th 2018, 00:00:00.000      conversation-archived     2
6   July 29th 2018, 00:00:00.000      conversation-archived     2
7   July 29th 2018, 00:00:00.000 conversation-auto-archived     2
8   July 30th 2018, 00:00:00.000      conversation-archived     3
9   July 30th 2018, 00:00:00.000      conversation-archived     2
10  July 30th 2018, 00:00:00.000 conversation-auto-archived     1
11  July 31st 2018, 00:00:00.000      conversation-archived     1
12 August 1st 2018, 00:00:00.000      conversation-archived     1
13 August 1st 2018, 00:00:00.000 conversation-auto-archived     1
14 August 2nd 2018, 00:00:00.000      conversation-archived     4
15 August 2nd 2018, 00:00:00.000      conversation-archived     1
16 August 2nd 2018, 00:00:00.000 conversation-auto-archived     2
```

This is the raw data:

```
df <- structure(list(time.per.day = c("July 27th 2018, 00:00:00.000", 
"July 27th 2018, 00:00:00.000", "July 28th 2018, 00:00:00.000", 
"July 28th 2018, 00:00:00.000", "July 29th 2018, 00:00:00.000", 
"July 29th 2018, 00:00:00.000", "July 29th 2018, 00:00:00.000", 
"July 30th 2018, 00:00:00.000", "July 30th 2018, 00:00:00.000", 
"July 30th 2018, 00:00:00.000", "July 31st 2018, 00:00:00.000", 
"August 1st 2018, 00:00:00.000", "August 1st 2018, 00:00:00.000", 
"August 2nd 2018, 00:00:00.000", "August 2nd 2018, 00:00:00.000", 
"August 2nd 2018, 00:00:00.000"), Top.0.type = c("conversation-archived", 
"conversation-archived", "conversation-archived", "conversation-archived", 
"conversation-archived", "conversation-archived", "conversation-auto-archived", 
"conversation-archived", "conversation-archived", "conversation-auto-archived", 
"conversation-archived", "conversation-archived", "conversation-auto-archived", 
"conversation-archived", "conversation-archived", "conversation-auto-archived"
), Count = c(2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L
))
```

I rename the columns (`colnames(df) <- c("date", "type", "retailer_code", "count")`) and manipulate the data to look a certain way, but now after using `as.Date(df$date, format='%B %d %Y')`, do some other maintenance:

```
 # Remove time and identifiers from date column
df$date <- gsub(", 00:00:00.000", "", df$date)
df$date <- gsub("st", "", df$date)
df$date <- gsub("nd", "", df$date)
df$date <- gsub("rd", "", df$date)
df$date <- gsub("th", "", df$date)
```

this is the resulting data frame:

```
         date      type count
1  2018-07-27 Completed     2
2  2018-07-27 Completed     1
3  2018-07-28 Completed     4
4  2018-07-28 Completed     1
5  2018-07-29 Completed     2
6  2018-07-29 Completed     2
7  2018-07-29    Missed     2
8  2018-07-30 Completed     3
9  2018-07-30 Completed     2
10 2018-07-30    Missed     1
11 2018-07-31 Completed     1
12       <NA> Completed     1
13       <NA>    Missed     1
14       <NA> Completed     4
15       <NA> Completed     1
16       <NA>    Missed     2
```

Here is a `dput` of the the resulting data frame:

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(17739, 17739, 17740, 17740, 
17741, 17741, 17741, 17742, 17742, 17742, 17743, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), class = "Date"), type = c("Completed", "Completed", 
"Completed", "Completed", "Completed", "Completed", "Missed", 
"Completed", "Completed", "Missed", "Completed", "Completed", 
"Missed", "Completed", "Completed", "Missed"), count = c(2L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```

Why is this going wrong now?

---

It was brought to my attention that `df$date <- gsub("st", "", df$date)` was converting `August` to `Augu` and as such this was causing the NA values to appear.

I changed it to `df$date <- gsub("1st", "", df$date)`, but this now causes other problems with the resulting data frame (rows 12-16 (inclusive)):

```
         date      type count
1  2018-07-27 Completed     2
2  2018-07-27 Completed     1
3  2018-07-28 Completed     4
4  2018-07-28 Completed     1
5  2018-07-29 Completed     2
6  2018-07-29 Completed     2
7  2018-07-29    Missed     2
8  2018-07-30 Completed     3
9  2018-07-30 Completed     2
10 2018-07-30    Missed     1
11 2018-07-03 Completed     1
12 0018-08-20 Completed     1
13 0018-08-20    Missed     1
14 0018-08-20 Completed     4
15 0018-08-20 Completed     1
16 0018-08-20    Missed     2
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: `as.Date(df$date, "%B %d %Y")` works for me with `NA` values in the end.

Comment: @RonakShah I don't understand - do you mean that you did get `NA` values in the end or not?  I don't want them - I want the actual date values in the resulting data frame.

Comment: How would you get actual values when you have dates like `"Augu 1 2018"  "Augu 1 2018"  "Augu 2 2018"  "Augu 2 2018" 
"Augu 2 2018"` ? you need to find a way in which it can be converted to complete months.

Comment: They are the complete months (not `Augu 1st 2018` but `August 1st 2018`)...

Comment: ohh..I get it now. `df$date <- gsub("st", "", df$date)` is replacing `st` of `August` to `Augu`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Originally,

```
df$date <- gsub("st", "", df$date)
```

was causing an issue as it was matching "st" of "August" as well as "1st". To overcome that we just need to replace "1st" with "1" as we need the date.

```
df$date <- gsub("1st", "1", df$date)
```

and then convert to date.

```
as.Date(df$date, "%B %d %Y")

#[1]  "2018-07-27" "2018-07-27" "2018-07-28" "2018-07-28" "2018-07-29" "2018-07-29"
#[7]  "2018-07-29" "2018-07-30" "2018-07-30" "2018-07-30" "2018-07-31" "2018-08-01"
#[13] "2018-08-01" "2018-08-02" "2018-08-02" "2018-08-02"
```

---

Ideally, hardcoding and replacing values is not a good idea which can cause such issues, hence, we can instead replace the values when a digit is followed by ordinal in one step instead of 4 separate `sub`s.

So after

```
df$date <- sub(", 00:00:00.000", "", df$date)
```

we can directly do,

```
df$date <- sub("(\\d+)(st|nd|rd|th)\\b", "\\1", df$date)
```

Comment: Ah yes, perfect. I've had a long day! Thank you, Ronak.

Comment: Your edit is great, but I have made one adjustment to it to incorporate the date conversion in the same process: `df$date <- as.Date(sub("(\\d+)(st|nd|rd|th)\\b", "\\1", df$date), format='%B %d %Y')`.

Comment: @MusTheDataGuy yeah..sure you can combine those steps into one. :)